# How to pass data from one component to another

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a Component called MainWizard Which is using many child components, Each Child component has an input form to take input for various fields.

To pass data from one child component to another I am using a service named wizardService.
for each shared variable I am having a subject in the service like below

```
    private warningSubject= new Subject<any>();
    
    setWarning(data){
        return this.warningSubject.next(data);
    }

    getWarning(){
      return this.warningSubject.asObservable();
    }
```

But ther are more than 20 subject like that for every variable that I need to share with other child components.

Questions:

1. Is it okay to use these many subjects in service to share data among components?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this?
3. If this way is fine, can it be further optimized with some other strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of inputs/outputs/services is getting unwieldy you could wrap multiple related inputs/outputs into a class or object. Alternatively, you could make the child components do more work and the parent do less work (i.e. make the child components "smarter" and the parent "dumber"). You could also consider a state management library such as [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/), [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/), or [Akita](https://github.com/datorama/akita), though that may be overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of service, you might try double binding and passing the data to the child component as done in [link](https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7)

Answer (score 0):

Create common service with all related data fields, this is the easy solution for this problem